# Cómo pasar varios parametros a JasperReport desde Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper

Tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy realizando unas facturas desde un formulario Swing a JasperReport.
Estoy tomando los campos del formulario y enviandolos como parámetros al Jasper para crear la factura.
La factura tiene un detalle que es donde estan los conceptos como tal. Y pueden ser 1 o mas de 1.
El problema es que cuando la factura tiene dos detalles esta solo me toma el ultimo.
Nose como hacer para que me tome ambos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi sale la factura en PDF solo con el ultimo detalle, el anterior se pierde.
[image: jav]

Codigo

```
  HashMap parametros = new HashMap();

 //Parametros para cargar los datos al reporte desde los campos de texto
            parametros.put("tipoDocumento", txtTipoDocumento.getText());
            parametros.put("invoiceNum", txtNumeroFactura.getText());
            parametros.put("nombreFacturador", txtNombreFacturador.getText());
            parametros.put("nitFacturador", txtNitEmpresa.getText());
            parametros.put("fechaEmision", txtFechaEmision.getText());
            parametros.put("fechaVencimiento", txtFechaVencimiento.getText());
            parametros.put("resolucionDian", txtResolucion.getText());
            parametros.put("formadepago", txtFormaPago.getText());
            parametros.put("mediodepago", txtMedioPago.getText());
            parametros.put("L_CUFE", txtlabelCufe.getText());
            parametros.put("cufe", txtCufe.getText());
            parametros.put("qr", txtQr.getText());
            parametros.put("nombreAdquiriente", txtVendidoA.getText());
            parametros.put("nitAdquiriente", txtDocumento.getText());
            parametros.put("direccionAdquiriente", txtDireccion.getText());
            parametros.put("telefonoAdquiriente", txtTelefonos.getText());

            //Datos del detalle de la tabla
          
         
            // Recorro la tabla y tomo la celda que necesito para enviarla como parametro
            for (int i = 0; i < tablaDetalle.getRowCount(); i++) {

                parametros.put("lineaItem",Integer.parseInt(tablaDetalle.getValueAt(i,0).toString()));
                                

                
            }
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo no solo imagenes por favor.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, un HashMap solo permite un valor por key... dado estás metiendo siempre las líneas con la clave `lineaItem`, pues siempre estás *machacando* el valor, y por eso siempre vale lo que valga el último que metes. Para que permita varios valores debería ser un `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>`, por ejemplo. Entonces podrías poner varios valores a cada key puesto que serían listas

Comment: Echale también un vistazo a la documentación, acerca de `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`.

Comment: @Benito-B me puedes dar un ejemplo por favor, ya que la verdad soy muy nuevo en esto

Comment: También toma en cuenta que el detalle debe ser un subreporte o un Componente/Elemento de tipo Lista.

Answer (score 0):

No vas a poder hacer eso pasando sólo los parámetros. Los parámetros son únicos

Para poder hacerlo tienes dos opciones:

- Si proviene de una base de datos, pasar los parámetros que necesites para ejecutar una consulta SQL con respecto a esos parámetros y en el report definir esa consulta SQL. Le tendrás que pasar además la conexión
- Si no proviene de una base de datos sino que son datos que tienes en objetos Java en tu aplicación de escritorio, tienes la opción de pasar una lista de objetos al report.  Para ello se crea un DataSource y se pasa al jasper. El jasper debe estar definido como lenguaje Java.

En esta página tienes un ejemplo de cómo crear un informe a partir de un Datasource Java [Java Bean Datasource IReport](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2009/12/14/java-bean-datasource/)